UFW Blocks certain entry repeatedly
I was checking the UFW logs and I see a lot of entries like this
[UFW BLOCK] IN=wlo1 OUT= MAC=01:00:xx:00:00:xx:xx:35:38:xx:xx:xx:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 

This is no my laptop MacID. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.
Some entries have a different tail value
SRC=192.168.31.100 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Is it something natural or I should be investigating? Thanks.

You may find this helpful: What could be the cause for these strange UFW block entries in my syslog?
